# c2dm android push notification broadcasting capacity per day

Tags: android, android-c2dm

We plan to implement C2DM Android for push notification.
With C2DM, an application server can broadcasts messages to Android devices through C2DM.
How much does C2DM supports an application server to broadcast a message per day to Android devices?
How many messages can C2DM can broadcasts per day for an application server?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

100 000 is the answer. But you could buy more... or use another service (Google "C2DM alternative")

Comment: so 100 000 broadcasts to a device/devices, like each mobile device could recieve 100 000 broadcasts from c2dm per day. Is it?

Comment: Well, each device does not have a real limit. But the google account you use to send push is limited to 100k, and sometimes, most of those messages just disapear...

Comment: I've just checked the google doc on C2DM, they have set the limit to 200k. You should take a look at this page: `http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/android/c2dm/quotas.html`

Comment: so via google acc, if you are broadcasting the common message to 100 devices (1 broadcast to 100 devices), then it will count as 100 push messages?

Comment: To put it simple, messages count = no. of devices that we are pushing a single broadcasting message from appliaction server